# Vuejs: Should I split views into small components?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, components

I have a project that has 2 folders for components - 1) `src/components/` and 2) `src/views`. In the first one I store general components such as a drawer or nav, and in the second I store pages (views).

The problem:
I have a `src/views/ViewHome` component where I got a long html in which I store sections - ‘about’, ‘popular’, ‘reviews’, etc. Should I split this component into more mini components, or leave it as is? And if I should,  which folder should I put them in? The `src/components/` folder is served for general components like nav, so I think it doesn’t suit.

I’m thinking about a solution :
Create a folder `views/ViewHome/`, put there a `ViewHome.vue` and create there a components folder for these parts of `ViewHome`. Would that be appropriate? And what would be your solution? Please, help.

Comment: The question is subjective and so doesn't fit SO. It's up to you how the folders are called. You can check existing opensource repos for some ideas. " is served for general components like nav" - it was your decision and this doesn't sound reasonable, because the name implies these are just components, not general components. If you needed a folder for common components, it could be /components/common or /common/components . "create there a components folder" - but these aren't views. A view is a special kind of a component that relies on being used as a child of <router-view>

Comment: You don't really need /views at all, although it may be easier to keep them separate, though you can always filter them by View suffix. If the app has strong feature-based modular structure, there could be /src/about/... and contain all types of files

Comment: @EstusFlask how is it up to me if I'll work in a team where there should possibly be some rules of how to structure the project. That's why I'm asking, to be prepared before I get hired.

Comment: @EstusFlask Oh I got it, thanks. So I'll just keep the views inside src/views, then for common components I'll create src/components/common. However, if I have multiple sections in each View, I think it would be better to create a subfolder inside src/components for the sections of each view, instead of mixing them all up in one src/components folder. Also, they should probably be called properly in order to maintain the project. For example, src/components/ViewHomeComponents?

Comment: @EstusFlask From the other side, these ViewHome partials are still a parts of a ViewHome component which is a child of router-view. Why not just create a folder inside views like views/partials and keep the parts of each view there?

Comment: Because these "partials" are just generic components, they don't have the additional behaviour that router views do, e.g. receiving route params through props, exposing router hooks, etc. From the design perspective it doesn't really matter if they are used in a view or somewhere else, and you may end up with almost all comps belonging to views this way. The same component could be used in more than one page, so it may belong to 1 feature but many pages. As for me, I keep my view comps lean, containing only page layout and data loading logic, the content is extracted, also makes testing easier

Answer (score 1):

A good way to structure the components used in 'ViewHome' is by creating a folder in the src/views directory named 'Home.'

Inside this 'Home' folder, you can place an `index.vue` file and put all related components within the same directory.
This makes sense because these components are mainly planned for use on the Home page.

So, I would recommend going with this approach for better organization.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations! I also think it's best to keep those parts of 'Home' somehere in the same src/views folder, rather then in the src/components/common where it is intuitively hard to find then.